# How to switch branch and trunk without merging

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any way to switch trunk to branch without merging? Basically, I need a branch to become trunk (current working copy), and trunk to become branch (or tag) as a backup.

Thanks.,

Comment: Use the switch command, enter the url and hit OK.

Comment: As I understand it simply "points" trunk to the branch. But doesn't actually make the physical switch of directories/code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're saying your current trunk is garbage, and you just want to replace it with an existing branch, and continue developing on trunk as if your branch had been trunk all along.

This is fairly easy. Normally, when you branch/tag, you do an "svn copy" (under the hood, anyway, that's how TortoiseSVN's branch/tag option works). So instead of using "svn copy", use an "svn move" to get your current trunk out of the way. In TortoiseSVN, you can easily do this  right in the repository browser with a few right-click menus.

Once your trunk is out of the way in its new branch/tag location, you need to get your desired branch onto trunk. You can either do the same "svn move" method, or use "svn copy" if you want it to stick around as a branch also. This can be done from the repo browser, or for the "copy" method you could also use the "branch/tag" dialog from a working copy, specifying trunk as the destination instead of the usual branches/tags folder.